# how to type prisma objects in parameters

Tags: prisma

I have a function that expects a prisma model / instance

How do I actually type this function signature? What I want is the type that is returned from a `prisma.SOMETABLE.find` like:

`const item = await prisma.nftCollection.findFirst()`

short code snippet below.

```js
import { Prisma, PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export class Buyer {

    async findColl() {
        const item = await prisma.nftCollection.findFirst()
        await this.buyItem(item)
    }

    // this is the param i want to type
    async buyItem(item: SOMETYPE) {
        clog.info('todo - buy', item)
    }
}
```

more detail here:
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/11737

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *@prisma/client* (see *node_modules/.prisma/client/index.d.ts*) you find the types of your models, which you defined in your Prisma schema. Let's say `Item` is your model.

Therefore you could do the following:

```js
import { Prisma, PrismaClient, Item } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export class Buyer {

  async findColl(): Promise<void> {
    const item = await prisma.nftCollection.findFirst();
    await this.buyItem(item);
  }

  async buyItem(item: Item | null): Promise<void> {
    clog.info('todo - buy', item);
  }
}
```

`Item` is the accordant type (imported from `@prisma/client`) and `buyItem` accepts an argument of `Item | null` since `findFirst` returns an `Item` or `null`. Of course you could check if `item` is `null` before calling `buyItem`, then it would be just `item: Item`.

If you add a selection set to `findFirst`, you might need to use `Partial<Item>`.

**Edit:** Just read your Github link. Instead of `Item` using `collection` should also be fine. Check *node_modules/.prisma/client/index.d.ts* if you find the definition of `type collection { ... }`.

Comment: OK that first line is what I needed. Are there any good guides on how to define your own models that sit on top of imported prisma types? coming from a datamapper or sequelize view. most of the tuts on prisma site are pretty basic.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know any good guides which go beyond the basic stuff. But what I do like is to map my models the following: `model Collection { ... @@map("collection") }` or `model Item { ... @@map("items") }`. Importing `Collection` or `Item` feels a bit more natural.